# AFNetworking and JSON parameter

Tags: ios, json, swift2, afnetworking-2, swifty-json

Sorry if it is a recurrent question, but I couldn't find any good answer.

Using AFNetworking and SwiftyJSON.

I need to do this:

```
    let locationJArray = JSON(myLocationArray)

    let params = [
         "deviceID" : deviceID
        ,"deviceAPIKey" : deviceAPIKey
        ,"location" : locationJArray
    ]
```

locationJArray content:

```
[
  {
    "theDirection" : -1,
    "latitude" : -22.90354,
    "longitude" : -43.20959,
    "theAccuracy" : 5,
    "theSpeed" : -1
  }
]
```

the error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

when I try to pass locationJArray to params value.

Instead, using myLocationArray directly to params value works, but data is completely unreadable by api.

params content using myLocationArray:

```
["deviceID": 68, "location": (
        {
        latitude = "-22.90354";
        longitude = "-43.20959";
        theAccuracy = 5;
        theDirection = "-1";
        theSpeed = "-1";
    }
), "deviceAPIKey": a4465be43ec2b4c3baa50d2ca5ee2be8]
```

How can I send a parameter value as JSON ?

Answer (score 0):

For those with same question:

```
let locationJArray = String(JSON(myLocationArray))

let params = [
     "deviceID" : deviceID
    ,"deviceAPIKey" : deviceAPIKey
    ,"location" : locationJArray
]
```

Casting JSON object as String solved the issue.